# How can I start an external Netty Server on a Spigot Server

Tags: java, netty, bukkit

I was trying to start an external Netty Server on a Spigot Server.

The only thing I tried was that I start it at the beginning but the Problem was than the Users can't Join and the Server times out.

This is the Code of the Netty-Client which should connect to a Netty-Server which is working well.

```
EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup = EPOLL ? new EpollEventLoopGroup() : new NioEventLoopGroup();
try {
    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
        .group( eventLoopGroup )
        .option( ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true )
        .option( ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true )
        .channel( EPOLL ? EpollSocketChannel.class : NioSocketChannel.class )
        .handler( new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
            protected void initChannel( Channel channel ) throws Exception {
                preparePipeline( channel );
            }
        } );

    ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.connect( 
        ReplaySpigotServer.getConnection().configuration.getString( "server-host" ),
        ReplaySpigotServer.getConnection().configuration.getInt( "server-port" ) )
        .sync();

    f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
} catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    eventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
```

Answer (score 2):

With your code, you start a server using `.connect().sync()`, then you wait for it to quit using `closeFuture().sync();`.

Because you are waiting till the connection is over, this means that the Bukkit/Spigot server cannot handle any user related packets while you are using the netty channel.

Since calling `eventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();` would mean that all open connections are closed, we need to use a certain approach to prevent this.

What you can do inside your plugin is creating a new `eventLoopGroup` inside the onEnable, then create a new netty connection later, and when you plugin is being disabled, tear down the connection.

```
private EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup;

public void onEnable(){
    eventLoopGroup = EPOLL ? new EpollEventLoopGroup() : new NioEventLoopGroup();
}

public void onDisable(){
    eventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
}

public void newConnection() {
     Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
        .group( eventLoopGroup )
        .option( ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true )
        .option( ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true )
        .channel( EPOLL ? EpollSocketChannel.class : NioSocketChannel.class )
        .handler( new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
            protected void initChannel( Channel channel ) throws Exception {
                preparePipeline( channel );
            }
        } );

    ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.connect( 
        ReplaySpigotServer.getConnection().configuration.getString( "server-host" ),
        ReplaySpigotServer.getConnection().configuration.getInt( "server-port" ) )
        .sync();

}
```